# What does this PHP syntax mean in layman's term?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to understand a syntax and I would greatly appreciate if someone can tell what this means in layman's term:

> Route::get('/member-profile-form', ['as' => 'newmemberprofileform', 'uses' => 'User\MemberProfileFormController@showForm']);

Particularly the one that says 'as'...
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `get()` is the method of `Route` class, and you are calling it with 2 parameters. The first one is the `URI`, the second one is the `array` having 2 indexes in it.

here,

`as` is used to give the `URI` a name, means its a `named route`.

`uses` define the `Controller` function by which this `URI` is served and its a kind of `get` request here.

According to your question line **Particularly the one that says 'as'** is used for making a named route.

**Note:** Giving your route a name with the `as` option allows you to easily reference that route in other parts of your app. Thanks @Jamesgarrett for reminding me of this.

[Named Route Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes)

Comment: just to add to that - giving your route a name with the as option allows you to easily reference that route in other parts of yr app. doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes

Comment: @jamesgarrett: thanks for reminding me of this. I have added it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I'm so happy you guys at stackoverflow is here to rescue

Comment: Sounds great !! Enjoy the coding